# GTK: How to make labels as buttons (sort of list)

Tags: user-interface, gtk

In GTK+ I would like to have a vertical list of labels, that a user can scroll. A user can click on any label and it will go to it's own callback function.

Right now I'm using a vertical area of buttons, but I really do not like having buttons. To give a good example, what I am trying to achieve would be considered very similar to a ListView in Android:

[image: Picture of an Android ListView]

Is it possible to achieve this? I have tried replacing my buttons with labels but the signals stopped working (which would make sense). The GtkList is depecrated, and I am not sure what I am supposed to use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`GtkTreeView`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkTreeView.html) with [`GtkListStore`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkListStore.html) ( [`GtkTreeSelection`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkTreeSelection.html) for selection in `GtkTreeView` ). For scrolling of course you will make use of [`GtkScrolledWindow`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkScrolledWindow.html). Using `GtkTreeView` can be a little intimidating for a beginner but there are quite a few tutorial available online [like this one](http://scentric.net/tutorial/treeview-tutorial.html). Also, if you can install `gtk-demo` application  (part of `gtk2.0-examples` package on Ubuntu) which demonstrates using Gtk widgets along with code, it will be quite helpful for you.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! I will look at this tutorial and try this solution soon. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do as well (if you really want to use labels) is to just put each of them into a GTKEventBox, and then set the event mask to receive mouse clicks.

EDIT:
Example:

```
GtkWidget* gtk_clickable_label_new(const gchar *str)
{
    GtkWidget *eventbox, *label;

    label = gtk_label_new(str);
    gtk_widget_show(label);

    eventbox = gtk_event_box_new();
    gtk_widget_add_events(eventbox, GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(eventbox), label);

    return eventbox;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting your labels in a GtkVBox in a GtkScrolledWindow?

Comment: Yes. The problem is that when I click the labels do not respond with the callback as they do with buttons. This is the problem I have.

Comment: I have a doubt that GtkLabel will allow to use g_signal_connect(). I can't find any answer online though.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a bunch of GtkButtons that have no hieght/depth.

To do this use gtk_button_set_relief and choose the GTKReliefStyle of GTK_RELIEF_NONE.

That's how I put buttons in GtkTreeViewColumn headers, it looks nice.

Try it!